# Creating a trigger and function in CartoDB

Tags: function, postgresql, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger and a function in CartoDB which uses PostgreSQL.  I want my trigger to fire each time an INSERT INTO happens on my table **obs**.  I want my function to update a value in two other tables **inland** and **coastal**.  So far I have tried this code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION inlanddisp()  
RETURNS trigger AS $$  
BEGIN
     UPDATE inland SET lt_dispatch_level = obs.named_lt_dispatch_level   
     FROM obs   
     WHERE obs.created_at = (SELECT MAX(created_at) FROM obs)   
     AND inland.cartodb_id = 1
END;  
$$
```

---

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_inland  
AFTER INSERT INTO obs  
ON inland  
FOR EACH ROW  
EXECUTE PROCEDURE inlanddisp();
```

How can I setup my function and trigger so they work properly? I am getting a syntax error at or near "CREATE".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the language being used in your function as well as the closing semicolon. As for your trigger, you only need to specify which table the event is occurring. Your function will contain what action need to happen, so in this case updating your other two tables.

Try this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION inlanddisp()
RETURNS trigger AS $$

BEGIN

UPDATE inland SET lt_dispatch_level = obs.named_lt_dispatch_level
FROM obs
WHERE obs.created_at = (SELECT MAX(created_at) FROM obs)
AND inland.cartodb_id = 1;

(put your other query to update coastal here)

RETURN null;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER update_inland
AFTER INSERT 
ON obs
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE inlanddisp();
```

Refer to this [Trigger Procedure](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql-trigger.html) as a guide.

Comment: I think that worked, but now the link between my Google Form and my CartoDB table went out so I'll need to solve that and see if the trigger/function work.  Thank you! I will mark it as the answer once I solve that issue.

Comment: I had to drop the trigger to get my Google Form submission to begin appearing again.  My Google Form submission SQL statement is this:
INSERT INTO obs(named_lt_temperature,etc...)

Comment: Not quite sure how the trigger would affect the google form submission, however, to your previous issue, just add a "return null;" statement in the function and it should work. I updated the answer for you. I would assume since there was an error in the transaction, it would have halted your form from appearing. Try the new function, and let me know if it works.

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you again for all your help at the various stages of this project @JM, I really appreciate it!